# Is it possible to wrap Element ui el-option element?

Tags: element, html-select, word-wrap

Is there any way to wrap el-option element so that the width of it was not larger that the el-select field in which this element is?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fount an answer to my question:

```
.el-select__tags .el-select__tags-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4u6b9tye/13/